# Перевести файл SCSS в SASS при импорте в файл стилей

Tags: sass, scss

Файл стилей пишется на SASS. В этот файл стилей нужно подключить библиотеку @material, но суть в том, что файлы стилей в этой библиотеке написаны на scss. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как поступить в данном случае: как переконвертить подключаемый scss в sass?
Вот структура: [image: основной файл стилей]

Comment: а чем билдите? вэбпаком? Просто подключите нужный модуль к сборщику и будет он кушать и sass и scss и остальные

Comment: Gulp-ом собираю

Comment: поставьте пакет `npm i gulp-sass`

Comment: Gulp-sass уже стоит

Comment: должен кушать, какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: File to import not found or unreadable

Comment: ну так ясно, что не верный путь

Comment: просто какой-то затык

Comment: Можно скомпилировать scss и подключить сам готовый css файл если не принципиально

Comment: блин, хочу разобраться раз и навсегда

Comment: Моя логика. Есть основной файл стилей, в который подключаются через @import все требуемые стили библиотек. Далее прогоняем через gulp, который компилирует главный файл стилей (sass) в css, который в свою очередь подключен к html-странице

Comment: но вот на это @import "/node_modules/@material/textfield/mdc-text-field" сборщик ругается, что путь файл не найден или что он не может его прочитать

Comment: @Proshka У меня все работает, всмысле sass файл заинклудил scss https://imgur.com/a/MqI4Nl3

Comment: Скорее проблема в путях

Comment: ~ лучше, если в ноду тыкать